# Rsyslog expression with $programname is not working

Tags: rsyslog

got this in my rsysconf:

```
    $template TemplateLog,"%msg%\n"   
    $template DynamicLog,"%msg%\n"                                                                                                                            
    $template DynamicFile,"/var/log/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"    
    if ($programname == "test") then {local3.=debug    -/var/log/path.log;TemplateLog}                                                                  
    local3.=debug    -?DynamicFile;DynamicLog                                                                                                                 
    & stop
```

If I put away the if statement, it works well.
But I need to make the if statement working. What is wrong about it? Thank you for advice.

I tried to change the == to contains as suggested in one of answers, this does not help.

Is $programname containing same info as %PROGRAMNAME% ? This could cause the problem, maybe...

So acording to answer, I have made this:

```
$template TemplateLog,"%msg%\n"   
$template DynamicLog,"%msg%\n"                                                                                                                            
$template DynamicFile,"/var/log/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"           
template(name="pname" type="string" string="%PROGRAMNAME%")                                                                                               
set $!xyz = exec_template("pname");     
if ($!xyz contains'test') then {local3.=debug    -/var/log/path.log;TemplateLog}
local3.=debug    -?DynamicFile;DynamicLog                                                                                                                 
& stop
```

But unfortunately, this code is not working either. If I delete the if statement, the second DynamicFile is saved into test.log, so the value is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can always print the variable to see the output.
I think is something related to syntax, please try using `contains` instead of `==`.

You can assign it to a var using templates:

````
    $template DynamicLog,"%msg%\n"                                                                                                                            
    $template DynamicFile,"/var/log/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"    
    template(name="pname" type="string" string="%PROGRAMNAME%")
    set $!xyz = exec_template("pname");
    if ($!xyz contains 'test') then {local3.=debug    -/var/log/path.log;TemplateLog}                                                                 
    local3.=debug    -?DynamicFile;DynamicLog                                                                                                                 
    & stop```
````

Comment: No, this is not helping. Im almost sure it is something with syntax, cant see it tho, as Im really not into this

Comment: How do you print it tho?

Comment: Ok, so ```$programname``` and ```%PROGRAMNAME%``` are not the same, you can't just use "programname" as var.

Comment: So probably the ```if``` syntax is ok, but you can do it with template (I will edit my answer)

Comment: Thanks ! I have adjusted the answer, so it is according to current state, but it still unfortunately doesnt work :(